# Hiperlink + Eval + navigateURL

Tags: c#, asp.net

Gostaria de criar um link na linha do listview para navegar para uma url quando clicado. O campo "cidade" tem que completar a url para que o direcionamento seja feito corretamente.

```
<%#Eval("cidade")%>
```

Exemplo: Digamos que eu queira que o usuário seja direcionado para o wikipedia para visualizar as informações da cidade clicada e etc, tipo isso: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/"cidade"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na [***NavigateUrl***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.navigateurl(v=vs.110).aspx) do *componente* [***Hyperlink***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink(v=vs.110).aspx) que está dentro de um `ItemTemplate` do *componente* [***ListView***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx) faça:

```
NavigateUrl='<%#string.Format("https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/{0}", Eval("Cidade"))%>'>
```

---

***Código completo:***

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink 
                    ID="HyperLink1" 
                    runat="server" 
                    Text ='<%#Eval("Cidade") %>'
                    NavigateUrl='<%#string.Format("https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/{0}", Eval("Cidade"))%>'>                    
                </asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </div>
</form>
```

Nas versão mais atuais pode fazer assim também:

```
NavigateUrl='<%#$"https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/{Eval("cidade")}"%>'>
```

recurso esse chamado: [***C# 6 – String Interpolation***](http://www.marcioalthmann.net/2015/07/c-6-string-interpolation/)